# Pegar valor de formulário

Tags: php, formulário, doctrine, symfony-2

Esse é meu formulário twig.

```
<form id="csv" action="{{ path('faturamento_csv') }}" method="post">
    {% for elm, value in filtroLocais %}
         <input type="hidden" name="{{ elm }}" value="{{ value }}">
    {% endfor %}
         <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
              <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i>
              Gerar CSV
         </button>
</form>
```

Como resultado do formuário eu tenho isso:

```
<input type="hidden" value="25" name="0">
<input type="hidden" value="147" name="1">
```

Como faço pra pegar esses valores corretamente no Controller?
Pelo que eu consigo identificar, o formulário não envia nenhum valor com o nome "idLocal"

```
            $form = $this->createForm( new LogPesquisaType() );
        $form->bind( $request );
        $data = $form->getData();

        $filtroLocais = array(); // Inicializa array com locais a pesquisar
        foreach ( $data['idLocal'] as $locais ) {
                array_push( $filtroLocais, $locais->getIdLocal() );
        }

        $printers = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository( 'CacicCommonBundle:LogAcesso')
                ->faturamentoCsv( $data['dtAcaoInicio'], $data['dtAcaoFim'], $filtroLocais);
```

Comment: Qual o problema com seu código? Dá algum erro? . . . Você pode [edit] ^^^^ a pergunta para adicionar informações.

Comment: não apresenta nenhum erro, mas não consigo pegar esses valores no controller

Comment: já deu um var_dump no $_POST para ver o que vem ? posta o resultado ai

Comment: @Otto tem isso no $_POST array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "122" [1]=> string(3) "128" } s]ao exatamento os valores que eu preciso pegar :(

Comment: mas voce ta tentando pegar o $data['idLocal'] do array porém não existe

Comment: consegui :) Obrigado Otto. usando $_POST['0'] eu pego o valor. agora é só passar tudo para um array.. certo?

Comment: aqui  $data = $form->getData(); faz assim  $data['idLocal'] =  $form->getData(); se não me engano já resolve seu problema lembra de pontuar neh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mas voce ta tentando pegar o `$data['idLocal']` do array porém não existe

aqui `$data = $form->getData();` faz assim `$data['idLocal'] = $form->getData();` se não me engano ja resolve seu problema

Comment: não resolver completamente pq gera um erro: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getIdLocal() on a non-object. Mas ai já é outro problema. Obrigado!

Comment: getIdLocal quer dizer que você esta buscando um objeto .... no que passei estamos passando um array do post para uma variavel somente ... continua sendo um array. Da um positivo ai